# xcode and c++ regular expressions?

Tags: c++, regex, xcode, macos, ide

I developed a sort of scripting language using Java as my parser, but now I'm trying to improve it by recreating it with c++ in Xcode. I really need REGEX to make it work, but I'm not sure how to use REGEX with C++.

Does the newest version of Xcode (the Mac IDE) have a C++ REGEX library built into it? If so, what is it and how do I use it? If not, how can I get one and have Xcode recognize it?

Comment: 1. It's not XCode, it's Xcode. 2. Xcode doesn't have built-in language features, libraries... it's not a compiler, it's an IDE. 3. If plain ol' C suits you, you may use the POSIX C header/libraey `regex.h`

Comment: 1) is somewhat irrelevant, but thanks. I'll make sure to write it properly. 2) I know, but some IDE's package libraries (perhaps that's the wrong term, granted) with them that you can use. I'm also not sure which version of the c++ compiler it uses and what it has on it. 3) I'd rather use c++, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Regular expressions are a lousy way to parse a scripting language.  Have a look at flex and other parser generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libc++ (which is available in Xcode 4.3 and will become the preferred standard library version  in the next version, IIRC) supports the C++11 <regex> header.

Comment: Thanks! How do I use libc++ in my project? When I try to #include <regex> it tells me it that can't find it.